# Content does not show/hide in the same digest cycle even when dependent on same variable. How can I fix this?

Tags: angularjs

These two lines are directly adjacent in a template just as they are here:

```
<button ng-show="!lastView()" sp-button="default" class="floatRight" ng-click="nextView()">Next</button>
<span ng-show="lastView()" class="floatRight">No more pressing left... </span>
```

when lastView() goes from `false` to `true`, the next button and the alternative text are both visible for a brief moment before the button disappears.

Is there any simple fix to this problem? Obviously both elements should never show at the same time as their ng-show conditions are inverted.

Comment: How many times takes you lastView function ?

Comment: post your nextView() and lastView() functions

Comment: Why are my functions relevant? I think there should be a way to solve this without having to know anything about my functions. The ng-show conditions are inverted after all. Why is that not enough?

Comment: FYI, I also tried ng-switch but that didn't help.